# Growth factor of the golden spiral

Tags: geometry, golden-ratio

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral) says, that

> a golden spiral is a logarithmic spiral whose **growth factor is φ**, the golden ratio.

However, other sources<sup>[[only in Czech, sorry]](https://www.geogebra.org/m/MCnRm7WR)</sup> say that the "growth factor" of a spiral is actually a scale factor of the radius after "an entire loop". (Δθ = 360°)

Using [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWQLH.png) (Wikipedia again) and the idea above, radius for zero angle would be 1. Makes perfect sense, doesn't it?

Radius for **2π rad** (or one loop), however, would be **φ<sup>4</sup>**, so the ratio between the two radii (on the beginning and at the end of the loop) would be *φ to the power of four* instead.

### Is Wikipedia wrong? Or is the used definition of growth factor?

And if so, what is the correct definition for the growth factor of a logarithmic spiral? Is it actually calculated only for π/2, or am I missing something?

Comment: The next sentence in the (English) Wikipedia article you linked to clarified that "growth factor" refers to a quarter turn, not a full one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As T. Bongers mentioned, the golden ratio $\varphi$ is for a quarter turn. It's apparent why when you see this image:

[image]

[Credit](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-golden-ratio)